# Quick question about grammars

Tags: formal-grammar

I'm trying to discern whether or not I am answering this question correctly. If someone could shine some light on this, that would be greatly appreciated. So let's state for instance that we have the following phrase-structure grammar:

Which phrase-structure grammar will consist of only the bit strings 0,1, and 11? Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I assume the answer would be D. So here are the possible answers.

```
A. S->1A
   S->0B
   A->0
   B->1
```

From Option A, I don't see how it could be the answer as S->1A->10 or alternatively S->0B->01. 11 is not a part of that language.

```
B. S->1
   S->0A
   A->0S
```

From Option B, I don't see how this can be the answer as well the possible combinations all commence with 0, thus having an 11 as part of the language is impossible/improbable. Please correct me if I'm incorrect.

```
C. S->1A
   A->0B
   B->1A
   B->1B
```

Now from option C, I can see how this COULD BE an answer, however, there is no way to end a derivation with a number. Derivations all end with a letter.

```
D. S->0
   S->1
   S->11
```

This answer seems to be the most logical, but it also seems like a trick. All are S or starting symbols. Is this the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, D is the only correct answer, more or less for the reasons you said. C does not derive any strings: a derivation is incomplete until all nonterminal symbols are eliminated, and in C this never happens. B derives one string that does not begin with a zero, namely `1`, but as you observed it does not derive`11`. (It also doesn't derive `0`.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming MJD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, that only grammar D generates the required language.  And your explanations are mostly correct, except for a few minor errors.

For grammar B, you said “the possible combinations all commence with 0”, which is *almost* true, but grammar B also generates the string `1`.  But as you said, it fails to derive `11`, so it isn't what is wanted.  (It also derives `001`, `00001`, and so on.)

For grammar C, you said “derivations all end with a letter”.  Usually some of the symbols are designated as “terminal” and the rest as “non-terminal”, and the language only includes sequences of *terminal* symbols.  Sequences that include non-terminal symbols are unfinished.  Sometimes the lists of terminal and non-terminal symbols are given explicitly, but when they aren't as in this case, you are supposed to assume that capital letters like A, B, and S are non-terminal, and digits and lowercase letters are terminal. All of this is by way of saying that the language derived by grammar C is actually *empty* and contains no strings at all: there is no way to finish any derivation!

But your idea of what is going on seems generally correct, and you did get the right answer to this tricky-seeming question.